# find option available to omit leading './' in result

Tags: bash, find

I think this is probably a pretty n00ber question but I just gotsta ask it.
When I run:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.ogg" \)
```

and get:

```
./01.Adagio - Allegro Vivace.mp3
./03.Allegro Vivace.mp3
./02.Adagio.mp3
./04.Allegro Ma Non Troppo.mp3
```

why does find prepend a `./` to the file name? I am using this in a script:

```
fList=()
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    fList+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find . -type f \( -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.ogg" \) -print0)
fConv "$fList" "$dBaseN"
```

and I have to use a bit of a hacky-sed-fix at the beginning of a `for` loop in function 'fConv', accessing the array elements, to remove the leading `./`. Is there a `find` option that would simply omit the leading `./` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask it to search under `/tmp`, the results will be on the form `/tmp/file`:

```
$ find /tmp
/tmp
/tmp/.X0-lock
/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.cUkZfY
```

If you ask it to search under `.` (like you do), the results will be on the form `./file`:

```
$ find .
.
./Documents
./.xmodmap
```

If you ask it to search through `foo.mp3` and `bar.ogg`, the result will be on the form `foo.mp3` and `bar.ogg`:

```
$ find *.mp3 *.ogg
click.ogg
slide.ogg
splat.ogg
```

However, this is just the default. With GNU and other modern `find`s, you can modify how to print the result. To always print just the last element:

```
find /foo -printf '%f\0'
```

If the result is `/foo/bar/baz.mp3`, this will result in `baz.mp3`.

To print the path relative to the argument under which it's found, you can use:

```
find /foo -printf '%P\0'
```

For `/foo/bar/baz.mp3`, this will show `bar/baz.mp3`.

However, you shouldn't be using `find` at all. This is a job for plain globs, as suggested by R Sahu.

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(*.mp3 *.ogg)
echo "Converting ${files[*]}:"
fConv "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: nice, the `shopt -s nullglob` removes the need for conditional test to check if file exists. I never used, actually don't know anything about so have not used `shopt`s. Slick.

Answer (score 3):

The ./ at the beginning of the file is the path. The "." means current directory.

You can use "sed" to remove it.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.ogg" \) | sed 's|./||'
```

I do not recommend doing this though, since `find` can search through multiple directories, how would you know if the file found is located in the current directory?

Comment: The reason it is prepended is that you can run `find` on multiple directories, so the output needs to be unambiguous. `find .` could be `find . path` and then how would you know which matches are in `path` if the output didn't show this?

Comment: piping find result to `sed` makes more sense to me since the edit would be easier to understand being next to the output rather than at the beginning another block of code. I only want to search $PWD which is why I specified `-maxdepth 1`, so it matters little in this instance that the results are prepended.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.ogg" \) -exec basename "{}" \;
```

Having said that, I think you can use a simpler approach:

```
for file in *.mp3 *.ogg
do
   if [[ -f $file ]]; then
       # Use the file
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `-maxdepth` is `1`, you can simply use `ls`:

```
$ ls *.mp3 *.ogg
```

Of course, that will pick up any directory with a `*.mp3` or `*.ogg` suffix, but you probably don't have such a directory anyway.

Another is to munge your results:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name "*.mp3" -o -name "*.ogg" \) | sed 's#^\./##'
```

This will remove all `./` prefixes, but not touch other file names. Note the `^` anchor in the substitution command.

Comment: funny you say: actually the script does in fact create a dir to dump converted files into with parent dir name appended with '_128kmp3'. But still shouldn't match since it is not '_128k.mp3'